# Trying to get place name and add it to output csv file from a large osm file

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osmfilter

I have about 1000+ locations that I've filtered in a country with osmfilter on a .osm file, I want to create a .csv file with their id, name, lat, lon, and **PLACE** (name of the administrative boundary they are in: say a state in USA).

I filtered some points using tags with the key sport, and since the file was downloaded from geofabrik I thought that place would be included in the file.

I attempted:

```
osmconvert filterlist-country.osm  --csv="@id name @lon @lat place" --csv-headline --csv-separator=,  -o=test.csv
```

I expected to get the .csv with the name of the administrative boundary but I get nothing where "place" should be.

Do I have to download another file and get the place from there? Can't I use the one I have?

Comment: Update: Already solved it using other tools, still if anyone knows how it's done I'm still curious :)